# SVG is not showing center while animating and after finished animation

Tags: javascript, svg

I am new in javascript & SVG Can any one help me get out of this stuck
trying keep center clock image while resize using elem.style.left and elem.style.topp;
or any chance to use zoom function using plain javascript
or suggest any work around achieve get center of SVG element
or suggest any work around achieve get center of SVG element
or suggest any work around achieve get center of SVG element
or suggest any work around achieve get center of SVG element

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("clock1");  
 var pos = 0 
 var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
 var id2 = setInterval(frame2, 5);
  //resize div
 function frame() {
 
  if (pos == 600) { 
    clearInterval(id); //stop animation  
  } else {
      //set defualt size of SVG (elem)
   elem.style.width = "0px"; 
   elem.style.height = "0px";
   pos++; 
    //resize width & Height for zoom svg (elem)
   if(pos < 600) {
    elem.style.width = pos + 'px'; 
    elem.style.height = pos + 'px'; 
   } else {
    elem.style.width = pos + 'px'; 
    elem.style.height = pos + 'px';   
   };  
   };
  };
 
  //function for set center of svg (elem)
 function frame2 () {
 elem.style.top = "0px";
 elem.style.left = "0px" ;
 if(elem.style.left > "0.5px") {
  var test =parseInt(document.getElementById("wrapper").style.width); // for get center
  var test2 = parseInt(elem.style.width); //remove px
  var left = parseInt(elem.style.left); //remove px
  var calculatedwidth = Math.max(((test - test2) / 2) + 
                                                left) ;// for get center
  var modifiedwidth = calculatedwidth;
  elem.style.left =calculatedwidth; //set position
  elem.style.top =calculatedwidth; //set position
  
  };
  };
```

```css
#clock1 {
      width: 219px;
    height: 207px;
  position: absolute;
 
  background-color:#fff;
 /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/ 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW -->
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width:234px; height:258px; background-color:green; overflow:hidden; justify-content: center; top: 0px !important; left: 0px; position: absolute;" id="wrapper" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="210mm" height="297mm" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd;position: absolute;  " 
viewBox="0 0 200 200"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="clock1"   >
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil1 {fill:black}
    .fil2 {fill:#AA0000}
    .fil0 {fill:white}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1" >
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <g id="_239192552">
   <circle id="_239615328" class="fil0" cx="107.366" cy="108.741" r="79.375"/>
   <g>
    <g>
     <g>
      <g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239615616" class="fil1" />
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239615664" class="fil1" />
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239615736" class="fil1" />
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602424" class="fil1" />
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602256" class="fil1" points="151.673,45.1189 154.182,46.9414 149.626,53.2125 147.117,51.39 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602160" class="fil1" points="158.081,50.0988 160.385,52.1735 155.198,57.934 152.894,55.8593 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602112" class="fil1" points="163.933,55.7213 166.008,58.0255 160.247,63.2122 158.172,60.908 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602208" class="fil1" points="169.165,61.9246 170.988,64.433 164.716,68.9892 162.894,66.4808 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602376" class="fil1" points="177.548,75.7965 178.809,78.629 171.728,81.7818 170.467,78.9493 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239601872" class="fil1" points="180.607,83.313 181.565,86.2618 174.193,88.6571 173.235,85.7083 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239601008" class="fil1" points="182.864,91.1082 183.509,94.141 175.927,95.7526 175.282,92.7198 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239601488" class="fil1" points="184.294,99.0965 184.618,102.18 176.909,102.99 176.585,99.9067 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239601464" class="fil1" points="104.265,31.2262 110.466,31.2262 110.466,54.4806 104.265,54.4806 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239601272" class="fil1" points="143.438,40.0609 148.808,43.1615 139.506,59.2726 134.136,56.172 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239601392" class="fil1" points="172.945,67.2983 176.046,72.6687 159.935,81.9705 156.834,76.6001 "/>
       </g>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g>
      <g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239601440" class="fil1" points="184.618,115.302 184.294,118.385 176.585,117.575 176.909,114.491 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239600984" class="fil1" points="183.509,123.341 182.864,126.373 175.282,124.762 175.927,121.729 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602544" class="fil1" points="181.565,131.22 180.607,134.168 173.235,131.773 174.193,128.824 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602760" class="fil1" points="178.809,138.853 177.548,141.685 170.467,138.532 171.728,135.7 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602496" class="fil1" points="170.988,153.049 169.165,155.557 162.894,151.001 164.716,148.492 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239602928" class="fil1" points="166.008,159.456 163.933,161.76 158.172,156.574 160.247,154.269 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239584160" class="fil1" points="160.385,165.308 158.081,167.383 152.894,161.622 155.198,159.548 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239584424" class="fil1" points="154.182,170.54 151.673,172.363 147.117,166.092 149.626,164.269 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239584304" class="fil1" points="140.31,178.923 137.477,180.185 134.325,173.103 137.157,171.842 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239584256" class="fil1" points="132.793,181.983 129.845,182.941 127.449,175.569 130.398,174.61 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239583992" class="fil1" points="124.998,184.239 121.965,184.884 120.354,177.302 123.387,176.657 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239583776" class="fil1" points="117.01,185.669 113.926,185.993 113.116,178.284 116.2,177.96 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239583248" class="fil1" points="184.88,105.64 184.88,111.841 161.626,111.841 161.626,105.64 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239583392" class="fil1" points="176.046,144.813 172.945,150.183 156.834,140.881 159.934,135.511 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239583464" class="fil1" points="148.808,174.32 143.438,177.421 134.136,161.31 139.506,158.209 "/>
       </g>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g>
      <g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239583440" class="fil1" points="100.805,185.993 97.7213,185.669 98.5315,177.96 101.615,178.284 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239583704" class="fil1" points="92.7658,184.884 89.733,184.239 91.3446,176.657 94.3774,177.302 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239582528" class="fil1" />
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239583128" class="fil1" points="77.2538,180.185 74.4213,178.923 77.5741,171.842 80.4066,173.103 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239582720" class="fil1" points="63.0578,172.363 60.5494,170.54 65.1056,164.269 67.614,166.092 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239582480" class="fil1" points="56.6503,167.383 54.3461,165.308 59.5328,159.548 61.837,161.622 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239582648" class="fil1" points="50.7983,161.76 48.7236,159.456 54.4841,154.269 56.5588,156.574 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239583080" class="fil1" points="45.5662,155.557 43.7437,153.049 50.0148,148.492 51.8373,151.001 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239582672" class="fil1" points="37.183,141.685 35.9219,138.853 43.0032,135.7 44.2643,138.532 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239564880" class="fil1" points="34.1239,134.169 33.1658,131.22 40.5379,128.825 41.496,131.773 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239564976" class="fil1" points="31.8672,126.373 31.2226,123.341 38.8047,121.729 39.4493,124.762 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239564832" class="fil1" points="30.4376,118.385 30.1135,115.302 37.8225,114.491 38.1466,117.575 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239564376" class="fil1" points="110.466,186.255 104.265,186.255 104.265,163.001 110.466,163.001 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239564304" class="fil1" points="71.2935,177.421 65.9231,174.32 75.2249,158.209 80.5953,161.31 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239564352" class="fil1" points="41.7862,150.183 38.6856,144.813 54.7967,135.511 57.8973,140.881 "/>
       </g>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g>
      <g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239564112" class="fil1" points="30.1135,102.18 30.4376,99.0965 38.1466,99.9067 37.8225,102.99 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239564184" class="fil1" points="31.2225,94.141 31.8671,91.1082 39.4492,92.7198 38.8046,95.7526 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239564472" class="fil1" points="33.1657,86.2619 34.1238,83.3131 41.4959,85.7084 40.5378,88.6572 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239564664" class="fil1" points="35.9219,78.629 37.183,75.7965 44.2643,78.9493 43.0032,81.7818 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239441184" class="fil1" points="43.7437,64.433 45.5662,61.9246 51.8373,66.4808 50.0148,68.9892 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239441592" class="fil1" points="48.7236,58.0255 50.7983,55.7213 56.5588,60.908 54.4841,63.2122 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239441520" class="fil1" points="54.3461,52.1735 56.6503,50.0988 61.837,55.8593 59.5328,57.934 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239441736" class="fil1" points="60.5494,46.9414 63.0578,45.1189 67.614,51.39 65.1056,53.2125 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239441112" class="fil1" points="74.4213,38.5582 77.2538,37.2971 80.4066,44.3784 77.5741,45.6395 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239441304" class="fil1" points="81.9378,35.4991 84.8866,34.541 87.2819,41.9131 84.3331,42.8712 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239441424" class="fil1" points="89.733,33.2424 92.7658,32.5978 94.3774,40.1799 91.3446,40.8245 "/>
         </g>
         <g>
          <polygon id="_239441880" class="fil1" points="97.7213,31.8128 100.805,31.4887 101.615,39.1977 98.5315,39.5218 "/>
         </g>
        </g>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239458728" class="fil1" points="29.851,111.841 29.851,105.64 53.1054,105.64 53.1054,111.841 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239458584" class="fil1" points="38.6857,72.6687 41.7863,67.2983 57.8974,76.6001 54.7968,81.9705 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
        <polygon id="_239458632" class="fil1" points="65.9231,43.1614 71.2935,40.0608 80.5953,56.1719 75.2249,59.2725 "/>
       </g>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g>
    <polygon id="_239458056" class="fil1" points="66.8412,85.592 65.8423,80.2027 71.2316,79.2038 122.337,114.328 117.947,120.716 "/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <polygon id="_239458128" class="fil1" points="161.983,65.2266 166.314,65.9125 165.628,70.2434 91.6291,124.007 87.9841,118.99 "/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <path id="_239458080" class="fil2" d="M121.273 39.5827l0.9194 -0.597 0.597 0.9194 -4.6832 22.7785 -1.8197 -0.3868 4.9865 -22.7141zm-8.6079 39.3785l1.9713 0.419 -10.5894 52.4291 -3.0328 -0.6446 11.6509 -52.2035z"/>
     <path id="_239458248" class="fil2" d="M117.358 61.7319c5.0113,1.0653 8.2298,6.0212 7.1646,11.0325 -1.0652,5.0114 -6.0212,8.2298 -11.0325,7.1646 -5.0113,-1.0651 -8.2296,-6.0211 -7.1644,-11.0324 1.0651,-5.0114 6.0211,-8.2298 11.0323,-7.1646l0 -0.0001zm-0.9669 4.5493c-2.5056,-0.5325 -4.9836,1.0767 -5.5162,3.5823 -0.5326,2.5057 1.0766,4.9837 3.5822,5.5163 2.5056,0.5325 4.9836,-1.0767 5.5162,-3.5823 0.5326,-2.5057 -1.0767,-4.9837 -3.5823,-5.5163l0.0001 0z"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your code you have an open div (no closing tag) and lots of polygons with no `points` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to zoom into the clockface while the clockface always remains horizontally and vertically centered - is that correct?

If so, instead of using javascript, one alternative approach is to animate the clockface using the CSS `scale` transformation:

```
transform: scale([VALUE])      // a value of 1 represents normal size
```

**Working Example:**

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#clock1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color:#fff;
  animation: zoomClock 4s ease-out;
}

.fill0 {fill: white;}
.fill1 {fill: black;}
.fill2 {fill: #AA0000;}

@keyframes zoomClock {

   0% {transform: scale(0);}
 100% {transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="clock1">
 <g>
  <g>
   <circle class="fill0" cx="107.366" cy="108.741" r="79.375" />
   <g>
    <g>
     <g>
      <g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" />
          <polygon class="fill1" />
          <polygon class="fill1" />
          <polygon class="fill1" />
       </g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="151.673,45.1189 154.182,46.9414 149.626,53.2125 147.117,51.39 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="158.081,50.0988 160.385,52.1735 155.198,57.934 152.894,55.8593 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="163.933,55.7213 166.008,58.0255 160.247,63.2122 158.172,60.908 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="169.165,61.9246 170.988,64.433 164.716,68.9892 162.894,66.4808 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="177.548,75.7965 178.809,78.629 171.728,81.7818 170.467,78.9493 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="180.607,83.313 181.565,86.2618 174.193,88.6571 173.235,85.7083 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="182.864,91.1082 183.509,94.141 175.927,95.7526 175.282,92.7198 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="184.294,99.0965 184.618,102.18 176.909,102.99 176.585,99.9067 "/>
       </g>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="104.265,31.2262 110.466,31.2262 110.466,54.4806 104.265,54.4806 "/>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="143.438,40.0609 148.808,43.1615 139.506,59.2726 134.136,56.172 "/>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="172.945,67.2983 176.046,72.6687 159.935,81.9705 156.834,76.6001 "/>
      </g>
     </g>

     <g>
      <g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="184.618,115.302 184.294,118.385 176.585,117.575 176.909,114.491 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="183.509,123.341 182.864,126.373 175.282,124.762 175.927,121.729 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="181.565,131.22 180.607,134.168 173.235,131.773 174.193,128.824 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="178.809,138.853 177.548,141.685 170.467,138.532 171.728,135.7 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="170.988,153.049 169.165,155.557 162.894,151.001 164.716,148.492 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="166.008,159.456 163.933,161.76 158.172,156.574 160.247,154.269 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="160.385,165.308 158.081,167.383 152.894,161.622 155.198,159.548 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="154.182,170.54 151.673,172.363 147.117,166.092 149.626,164.269 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="140.31,178.923 137.477,180.185 134.325,173.103 137.157,171.842 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="132.793,181.983 129.845,182.941 127.449,175.569 130.398,174.61 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="124.998,184.239 121.965,184.884 120.354,177.302 123.387,176.657 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="117.01,185.669 113.926,185.993 113.116,178.284 116.2,177.96 "/>
       </g>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="184.88,105.64 184.88,111.841 161.626,111.841 161.626,105.64 "/>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="176.046,144.813 172.945,150.183 156.834,140.881 159.934,135.511 "/>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="148.808,174.32 143.438,177.421 134.136,161.31 139.506,158.209 "/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g>
      <g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="100.805,185.993 97.7213,185.669 98.5315,177.96 101.615,178.284 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="92.7658,184.884 89.733,184.239 91.3446,176.657 94.3774,177.302 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" />
          <polygon class="fill1" points="77.2538,180.185 74.4213,178.923 77.5741,171.842 80.4066,173.103 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="63.0578,172.363 60.5494,170.54 65.1056,164.269 67.614,166.092 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="56.6503,167.383 54.3461,165.308 59.5328,159.548 61.837,161.622 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="50.7983,161.76 48.7236,159.456 54.4841,154.269 56.5588,156.574 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="45.5662,155.557 43.7437,153.049 50.0148,148.492 51.8373,151.001 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="37.183,141.685 35.9219,138.853 43.0032,135.7 44.2643,138.532 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="34.1239,134.169 33.1658,131.22 40.5379,128.825 41.496,131.773 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="31.8672,126.373 31.2226,123.341 38.8047,121.729 39.4493,124.762 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="30.4376,118.385 30.1135,115.302 37.8225,114.491 38.1466,117.575 "/>
       </g>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="110.466,186.255 104.265,186.255 104.265,163.001 110.466,163.001 "/>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="71.2935,177.421 65.9231,174.32 75.2249,158.209 80.5953,161.31 "/>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="41.7862,150.183 38.6856,144.813 54.7967,135.511 57.8973,140.881 "/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g>
      <g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="30.1135,102.18 30.4376,99.0965 38.1466,99.9067 37.8225,102.99 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="31.2225,94.141 31.8671,91.1082 39.4492,92.7198 38.8046,95.7526 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="33.1657,86.2619 34.1238,83.3131 41.4959,85.7084 40.5378,88.6572 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="35.9219,78.629 37.183,75.7965 44.2643,78.9493 43.0032,81.7818 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="43.7437,64.433 45.5662,61.9246 51.8373,66.4808 50.0148,68.9892 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="48.7236,58.0255 50.7983,55.7213 56.5588,60.908 54.4841,63.2122 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="54.3461,52.1735 56.6503,50.0988 61.837,55.8593 59.5328,57.934 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="60.5494,46.9414 63.0578,45.1189 67.614,51.39 65.1056,53.2125 "/>
       </g>
       <g>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="74.4213,38.5582 77.2538,37.2971 80.4066,44.3784 77.5741,45.6395 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="81.9378,35.4991 84.8866,34.541 87.2819,41.9131 84.3331,42.8712 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="89.733,33.2424 92.7658,32.5978 94.3774,40.1799 91.3446,40.8245 "/>
          <polygon class="fill1" points="97.7213,31.8128 100.805,31.4887 101.615,39.1977 98.5315,39.5218 "/>
       </g>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="29.851,111.841 29.851,105.64 53.1054,105.64 53.1054,111.841 "/>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="38.6857,72.6687 41.7863,67.2983 57.8974,76.6001 54.7968,81.9705 "/>
        <polygon class="fill1" points="65.9231,43.1614 71.2935,40.0608 80.5953,56.1719 75.2249,59.2725 "/>
      </g>
     </g>
    </g>
   </g>
   <polygon class="fill1" points="66.8412,85.592 65.8423,80.2027 71.2316,79.2038 122.337,114.328 117.947,120.716 "/>
   <polygon class="fill1" points="161.983,65.2266 166.314,65.9125 165.628,70.2434 91.6291,124.007 87.9841,118.99 "/>
   <path class="fill2" d="M121.273 39.5827l0.9194 -0.597 0.597 0.9194 -4.6832 22.7785 -1.8197 -0.3868 4.9865 -22.7141zm-8.6079 39.3785l1.9713 0.419 -10.5894 52.4291 -3.0328 -0.6446 11.6509 -52.2035z"/>
   <path class="fill2" d="M117.358 61.7319c5.0113,1.0653 8.2298,6.0212 7.1646,11.0325 -1.0652,5.0114 -6.0212,8.2298 -11.0325,7.1646 -5.0113,-1.0651 -8.2296,-6.0211 -7.1644,-11.0324 1.0651,-5.0114 6.0211,-8.2298 11.0323,-7.1646l0 -0.0001zm-0.9669 4.5493c-2.5056,-0.5325 -4.9836,1.0767 -5.5162,3.5823 -0.5326,2.5057 1.0766,4.9837 3.5822,5.5163 2.5056,0.5325 4.9836,-1.0767 5.5162,-3.5823 0.5326,-2.5057 -1.0767,-4.9837 -3.5823,-5.5163l0.0001 0z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```